# C#: Get an integer representation of a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, integer, linear-regression

I am new to C# and I ran into the following problem (I have looked for a solution here and on google but was not successful):

Given an array of strings (some columns can possibly be doubles or integers "in string format") I would like to convert this array to an integer array.
The question only concerns the columns with actual string values (say a list of countries).

Now I believe a Dictionary can help me to identify the unique values in a given column and associate an integer number to every country that appears.
Then to create my new array which should be of type int (or double) I could loop through the whole array and define the new array via the dictionary. This I would need to do for every column which has string values.
This seems inefficient, is there a better way?

In the end I would like to do multiple linear regression (or even fit a generalized linear model, meaning I want to get a design matrix eventually) with the data.

EDIT:
1) Sorry for being unclear, I will try to clarify:

Given:

MAKE;VALUE ;GENDER 
AUDI;40912.2;m 
WV;3332;f 
AUDI;1234.99;m 
DACIA;0;m 
AUDI;12354.2;m 
AUDI;123;m 
VW;21321.2;f

I want to get a "numerical" matrix with identifiers for the the string valued columns 
MAKE;VALUE;GENDER 
1;40912.2;0 
2;3332;1 
1;1234.99;0 
3;0;0 
1;12354.2;0 
1;123;0 
2;21321.2;1

2) I think this is actually not what I need to solve my problem. Still it does seem like an interesting question.

3) Thank you for the responses so far.

Comment: Could you sum up your entire question in one sentence, to make it clearer to us?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to a double in C#?

Comment: Could you show a small example of what you *have* and what you *want*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take all the possible strings which represent an integer and puts them in a List.
You can do the same with strings wich represent a double.
Is this what you mean??

```
List<int> myIntList = new List<int>()
foreach(string value in stringArray)
{
      int myInt;
      if(Int.TryParse(value,out myInt)
      {
            myIntList.Add(myInt);
      }
}
```

Dictionary is good if you want to map each string to a key like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>();
myDictionary.Add(1,"CountryOne");
myDictionary.Add(2,"CountryTwo");
myDictionary.Add(3,"CountryThree");
```

Then you can get your values like:

```
string myCountry = myDictionary[2];
```

But still not sure if i'm helping you right now. Do you have som code to specify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but it does output the result you are looking for, from which you can create an appropriate data structure to use. I use a list of string but you can use something else to hold the processed data. I can expand further, if needed.


It does assume that the number of "columns", based on the semicolon character, is equal throughout the data and is flexible enough to handle any number of columns. Its kind of ugly but it should get what you want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class StringColIndex
    {
        public int ColIndex { get; set; }
        public List<string> StringValues {get;set;}
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var StringRepresentationAsInt = new List<StringColIndex>();
            List<string> rawDataList = new List<string>();
            List<string> rawDataWithStringsAsIdsList = new List<string>();
            rawDataList.Add("AUDI;40912.2;m");rawDataList.Add("VW;3332;f ");
            rawDataList.Add("AUDI;1234.99;m");rawDataList.Add("DACIA;0;m");
            rawDataList.Add("AUDI;12354.2;m");rawDataList.Add("AUDI;123;m");
            rawDataList.Add("VW;21321.2;f ");
            foreach(var rawData in rawDataList)
            {
                var split = rawData.Split(';');
                var line = string.Empty;
                for(int i= 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                {
                    double outValue;
                    var isNumberic = Double.TryParse(split[i], out outValue);
                    var txt = split[i];
                    if (!isNumberic)
                    {
                        if(StringRepresentationAsInt
                            .Where(x => x.ColIndex == i).Count() == 0)
                        {
                            StringRepresentationAsInt.Add(
                                new StringColIndex { ColIndex = i,
                                    StringValues = new List<string> { txt } });
                        }
                        var obj = StringRepresentationAsInt
                            .First(x => x.ColIndex == i);
                        if (!obj.StringValues.Contains(txt)){
                            obj.StringValues.Add(txt);
                        }
                        line += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? 
                            string.Empty : 
                            ("," + (obj.StringValues.IndexOf(txt) + 1).ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line += "," + split[i];
                    }
                }
                rawDataWithStringsAsIdsList.Add(line);
            }
            rawDataWithStringsAsIdsList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
            Console.ReadLine();
            /*
            Desired output:
            1;40912.2;0 
            2;3332;1 
            1;1234.99;0 
            3;0;0 
            1;12354.2;0 
            1;123;0 
            2;21321.2;1 
            */
        }
    }
}
```